# Payment methods "Wrong content type" after upgrade Magento from 1.6 to 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, payment, magento-1.6, ce-1.9.1.1

I've just upgraded magento version from 1.6 to 1.9.1.1. I go to system/configuration/sales/payment methods and got the following error:

[image: wrong content type]

I have tried to debug by going to this function on app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php:

```
public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $contentType = $this->getConfigData('content_type');
        $allowedMethods = array();
        if ($this->_isDomestic) {
            $allowedMethods = array_merge(explode(',', $this->getConfigData('doc_methods')),
                explode(',', $this->getConfigData('nondoc_methods'))
            );
        } else {
            switch ($contentType) {
                case self::DHL_CONTENT_TYPE_DOC:
                    $allowedMethods = explode(',', $this->getConfigData('doc_methods'));
                    break;
                case self::DHL_CONTENT_TYPE_NON_DOC:
                    $allowedMethods = explode(',', $this->getConfigData('nondoc_methods'));
                    break;
                default:
                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('usa')->__('Wrong Content Type.'));
            }
        }
        $methods = array();
        foreach ($allowedMethods as $method) {
            $methods[$method] = $this->getDhlProductTitle($method);
        }
        return $methods;
    }
```

I tried to **var_dump($contentType)** add get **NULL** value. What's wrong here ?

**UPDATE:**

My Content Type config in admin panel:

[image: content type DHL]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may have noticed in the given source code, the exception is thrown because `null` is not an allowed value for `$contentType`. `$contentType` is read from the system configuration:

```
$contentType = $this->getConfigData('content_type');
```

It is as simple as changing the system configuration setting to one of the allowed values. This can be done for instance via Admin Panel

```
System → Configuration → Sales → Shipping Methods → DHL → Content Type
```

or by adding a valid `core_config_data` entry for the config path `carriers/dhlint/content_type`.

Comment: I have already choosen content type in admin panel but still getting error.

Comment: This is a dropdown with only two non-empty options. So even if no value is stored to the database it will display _Documents_ there.  Please make sure the value is actually set in the database and the config cache is refreshed.

Comment: You're right. I've tried to save this setting again and it works. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I also get the same problem and resolved with following:
Goto `app > code > core > Mage  > Usa > etc > Config.xml`
Add Below code at `<carriers> <dhlint>` :

```
<content_type>D</content_type>
```

Comment: Please, if you have answer, write here. Don't give just links